# JSON in Environmental Variable on Netlify

Tags: git, firebase, deployment, environment-variables, netlify

I am building an AWS Lambda function that uses `ServiceAccountKey.json` for Firebase authentication. When deploying to Netlify, I don't want to expose this data in the git repo. Is there a way I can **save the whole JSON as an environmental variable**?

[image: JSON in environmental variable]

[image: Environmental variables on Netlify]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, you can store the json in the env var as a simple string.
Otherwise have a look a `jq` which allows you to run to read a json from a file and directly store it in an env var.

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

disclaimer: I work for Netlify's Support team.

While the prior suggestion that JSON can be used as a string without carriage returns embedded might work, it can be a bit challenging to get an environment variable to contain quote characters, which all non-trivial JSON I've ever seen uses.  Two different suggestions to do this differently:

1. to create the string with a placeholder instead and during build replace the placeholders with quotes.  I use the `@` character in this example, so your "JSON" would look like `{@type@: @service_account...`, and then you could use something like this in your build:

`echo -e "${JSON_VARIABLE//@/\"}" > file.json && do_your_normal_build`

2. you could also create a function (documentation here: https://www.netlify.com/docs/functions/) that returns it and that would even provide a reasonable Content-Type HTTP response header if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Netlify does not save JSON files for you unless you use netlify functions as a @fool mentioned below. But you shouldn't save json files with env variables into Git too. So the best way is to convert the data in your json file into an object and use that:

- convert the data inside that JSON into an object.
- our new object can then take .env variables, (you also need dotenv just in case)
- inject the object (serviceAccount for example) directly into the function that requires it.
- the secret error I had when I did the steps above was one of the .env variables had a "\n" which becomes "\\n" when turned into a string -> error messages don't really tell you that this is the problem.
- so you need to add this to that variable `.replace(/\\n/g, '\n')`
- for development, you have your .env files
- for production, you just add the env variables normally one by one inside netlify

here is my object as an example:

```
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = {
FIREBASE_KEY: {
    type: process.env.REACT_APP_SAK_TYPE,
    project_id: process.env.REACT_APP_SAK_PROJECT_ID,
    private_key_id: process.env.REACT_APP_SAK_PRIVATE_KEY_ID,
    private_key: process.env.REACT_APP_SAK_PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
    client_email: process.env.REACT_APP_SAK_CLIENT_EMAIL,
    client_id: process.env.REACT_APP_SAK_CLIENT_ID,
    auth_uri: process.env.REACT_APP_SAK_AUTH_URI,
    token_uri: process.env.REACT_APP_SAK_TOKEN_URI,
    auth_provider_x509_cert_url: process.env.REACT_APP_SAK_AUTH_PROVIDER_X509_CERT_URL,
    client_x509_cert_url: process.env.REACT_APP_SAK_X509_CERT_URL,
},
FIREBASE_DB: process.env.REACT_APP_FB_DATABASE_URL,
};
```

and the corresponding function that uses the keys:

```
const config = require('./config');
const serviceAccount = config.FIREBASE_KEY;
firebaseAdmin.initializeApp({ credential: firebaseAdmin.credential.cert(serviceAccount), databaseURL: config.FIREBASE_DB,});
```